# How to autocomplete brackets in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

new to python and spyder here.
 Is there a way to autocomplete brackets in spyder?!

Also is there a way to get auto indentation?
I risk making this too broad but is there also a way to make sure that if say I'm defining a function, I can simply click at the end of the function without highlighting everything to make it run.
Example:

```
def print_twice(Spam):
 print(Spam)
 print(Spam)
```

In the above I would like to run the last line but have spyder run everything from `def print_twice(Spam) to print(Spam)`
 Thanks and sorry if the question is annoying or already has an answer. Couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) My answers:

> Is there a way to autocomplete brackets in spyder?

Brackets are auto-completed automatically by default.

> Also is there a way to get auto indentation?

Auto-indentation works automatically too, after `:` or by aligning your code on open parenthesis.

> is there also a way to make sure that if say I'm defining a function, I can simply click at the end of the function without highlighting everything to make it run[?]

No, but you can create a cell to run your function. Cells are regions in your code delimited by comments of the form `# %%` and you can run them with `Ctrl+Enter` (run cell and stay on it) or `Shift+Enter` (run cell and advance to next one).